# Music symbols from LilyGlyphs package not working in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, music

I want to insert a few Music symbols (defined in the `lilyglyphs` package) using XeLaTeX. The following MWE used to compile fine and get the symbols in Ubuntu 18.04 (with TeXLive running, using the `sudo` command of Ubuntu). But after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, it's no longer working. Here is a minimal example along with all the error messages I get when compiling in XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}  %%% for musical symbol segno
\newcommand{\segno}{\large \lilyGlyph{scripts.segno}}
\begin{document}
\segno
\end{document}
```

I get several error messages of "missing .inp" such as  `` ! LaTeX Error: File `core/opticals.inp' not found `` (about 16 of them).
Then I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\segno ->\large \lilyGlyph{scripts.segno}
```

Reference:  https://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/unicodetex/latex/lilyglyphs/documentation/lilyglyphs.pdf
What am I missing here, or what is going wrong here?

Comment: works fine for me on on windows and with texlive 2021.

Comment: It used to work for me in Ubuntu 18.04 but fails in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: sorry but the ubuntu version is irrelevant. You should check the texlive and package version.

Comment: I am using the TeXLive in Ubuntu installed using "sudo"  command, so when I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, this TeXLive in Ubuntu might also gets upgraded.

Comment: compile your document and look in the log-file. Then you can see the versions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it works fine in a Windows  with MikTeX, so the issue is with the version I have in Ubuntu.

Comment: It seems the lilyglyphs  package is removed from the  xetex  (and possibly  misplaced in another place  like lualatex) in Ubuntu 20.04.